# Controller to be put inside Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I know it is possible to put Controller inside the Directive but I can't make it work of how it should be.
Added plunker link below.

**My Working Directive and Controller in One Javascript File**

This code works perfectly but I want to modify the `app.controller` and move it inside my `app.directive`

```
 app.controller('NameCtrl', function () {
   var vm = this;
   vm.namePattern =  '/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,25}$/';
 });

app.directive('nameDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    templateUrl: '/name.html'
  }
});
```

**some codes in my Index HTML file**

the first `<div>` is for the above code, and the second `<div>` is for my directive that I am working on(below).

```
<div ng-controller="NameCtrl" name-directive></div>
<!--<div name-directive></div> -->
```

**codes in templateURl name.html file**

it seems that `ng-pattern="ctrl.namePattern"` is not working at all, but it is completely working when I use the first JS code above and just modify it to `ng-pattern="namePattern"`.

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your first name"
     ng-model="username"
     ng-minlength="2"
     ng-maxlength="20"
     required
     ng-pattern="ctrl.namePattern"/>
```

**The codes I am working on my JS file (from the codes above)**

```
app.directive('nameDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.namePattern = '/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,25}$/';
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: '/name.html'
  }
});
```

I hope, I explain clearly my problem.

This is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/RakdDe?p=preview) of my sample code that I am working on.

Comment: The `ng-controller` directive uses `scope: true`. Your directive uses isolate scope, `scope: {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If aren't using isolated scope, just remove it from your directive or use `scope: true`...

```
app.directive('nameDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    //scope: {}, //Or you can use scope: true (It hasn't much sense in your case)
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.namePattern = '/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,25}$/';
    },
    templateUrl: '/name.html'
  }
});
```

See your directive working, [I've updated your PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/KgFzDl3qZeKErqUmcoP1?p=preview).